# Есть ли альтернатива SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod()

Tags: c, sdl

1) Как `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod()` работает внутри? Изменяет параметр прозрачности текстуры, который хранится в `RAM`, или же каждый вызов *стучит* в видеопамять? То есть вопрос, насколько этот вызов быстрый.

2) Есть ли альтернативный способ задать прозрачность выводимых при помощи `SDL_RenderCopy()` текстур глобально?

Суть проблемы вот в чем.

Я делаю редактор уровней, и одни и те же текстуры используются и при отрисовке интерфейса, и при отрисовке непосредственно уровня.

Сперва рисуется интерфейс, в котором есть списки (плитки) с типами блоков, которые можно установить на уровень. Перед отрисовкой каждой плитки при помощи `SDL_RenderCopy()` текстуре задается прозрачность при помощи `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod()`.

После отрисовки интерфейса отрисовывается сам уровень. Все блоки уровня должны иметь стопроцентную непрозрачность, поэтому перед отрисовкой каждого блока приходится снова звать `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod()`, потому что прозрачность текстуры отрисовываемого блока могла быть изменена при отрисовке интерфейса.

Конечно, перед отрисовкой уровня можно пройтись по всем текстурам и вновь задать им стопроцентную непрозрачность. Но есть ли другой способ? Способ задать прозрачность текстуры не в самой текстуре, а в настройках рендера?